# How to prevent the second onClick event from being executed before the first onClick event is completed on an ImageView

Tags: java, android, onclick, onclicklistener

In ANDROID Studio: How to prevent the second onClick event from being executed, before the first onClick event is completed on an ImageView.
Can we use Threading and Concurrency here using the andThen methods...?
Any help here will be highly appreciated.
Please find the code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public void executeFadingMethod(View view) {
        ImageView fish1= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fishOne);
        ImageView fish2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fishTwo);
        Fading fading = new Fading(fish1,fish2);
        fading.fadingMethod();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}


public class Fading {

    private ImageView fish1;
    private ImageView fish2;

    public Fading(ImageView fish1, ImageView fish2) {
        this.fish1 = fish1;
        this.fish2 = fish2;
    }

    public void fadingMethod(){
        float a = fish1.getAlpha();
        float b = fish2.getAlpha();
        Log.i("if-FishOneAfter", String.valueOf(fish1.getAlpha()));
        Log.i("if-FishTwoAfter", String.valueOf(fish2.getAlpha()));

        if (a == fish1.getAlpha() && b == fish2.getAlpha()) {
            fish2.animate().alpha(a).setDuration(2000);
            fish1.animate().alpha(b).setDuration(2000);
            fish1.setAlpha(b);
            fish2.setAlpha(a);
            Log.i("if-FishOneAfter", String.valueOf(fish1.getAlpha()));
            Log.i("if-FishTwoAfter", String.valueOf(fish2.getAlpha()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am capturing the values, when the second click is executed before the completion of the first click. Output:I/if-FishOneAfter: 0.0
I/if-FishTwoAfter: 1.0
I/if-FishOneAfter: 0.7497732
I/if-FishTwoAfter: 0.2502268

Comment: Easiest way will be create a flag and when image is clicked check if flag is false if so set flag true and process; if flag is true skip. At the end of operation you can reset flag to false

Comment: Thank you @shubham-srivastava. While there were multiple onClicks being passed, for every click it was taking a decimal in between 0 and 1. I convertred that to a whole number and passed the value to an if statement. With this, I was able to get another simple work around that solved the problem. However, I now have a need to understand how the OnClick event is handled by Android.